# Is there a way to add Xamarin.forms to a Universal Windows App(UWP)?

Tags: android, windows, xamarin, universal

I have a UWP application and I want it to be able to run into Android and also IOS using Xamarin.forms. Is there anyway to port it and run it on both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: Xamarin Forms is "Xaml" too, but works on top of a completly different framework.

If you have used a good architecture, you can use all your viewmodels (or whatever your ui logic is called) and just put a Xamarin.Forms UI on top of that. With a little luck, you can reuse a lot of the structure from your existing xaml, but as most names are different, it is almost a complete rewrite. Or you could put a native UI with Xamarin.Plattform UI on top of your code.

So if you want to go cross platt form, you have to add at least one completely new UI.

Comment: As of 2018, has XAML Standard changed anything?  Or does this answer still stand?

Comment: "I'm still standing!" *singsing* As of today, XAML Standard is more of an Idea than a real product. But the wheels keep on turning.